# What type of screw is this (3 slits)?

Tags: screws

It has three slits around the edge and no groove in the middle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the other side look like?

Comment: You could settle this once and for all - using a Dremel or a hacksaw blade, extend one of the slots straight across and try to unscrew it. That's less effort than finding the right bit of it is a screw

Comment: I'd like to know what this device is. I'd bet that the other end of the metal part is accessible, possibly behind another panel. (Just realized that this is a three year old question. D'oh!)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives), it is called a tri-groove screw.

Comment: If you search images for tri-groove screws you'll see that they're generally cone-shaped things much different than this one.

Comment: I found a few similar images and questions on some European forums (OP's images look like European power receptacle/cover to me) and most commenters are similarly stumped, this is not a typical screw/bolt head. Most tri-groove screws have truncated cone-shaped heads, but this T-groove screw came up in a search for "tri-groove" and was also mentioned on one of the forums. It's probably too late to help OP but I'll leave it here. http://www.superfastener.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/TGBMS.png

Answer (score 1):

That's not a screw. It's a *rivet*. I'd be willing to bet that the other end looks a bit like a doughnut, with its cylinder peened over the plastic to secure it.

The impressions in the head are not indicative that a tool may be used to remove the part. Instead, they're for positioning when the two plastic parts are fitted together and the rivet is pressed, or they're the *result* of the riveting process.

Then, if it *was* a screw, in plastic, you'd be able to easily twist it out with a needle-nose pliers.

Here's something similar. The heads of these hinge rivets have marks that resemble those of a screw head, but they're clearly not. When I find one that's closer, satisfying the oh-so-vigilant skeptics among you, I'll post it.

[image]

<sub>[Source](https://www.hoodhingerepair.com/hood-hinge-repair-process/)</sub>

Comment: Can you show any evidence that such a thing even exists? It seems awfully strange that a rivet would have three equally-spaced indentations around the rim like that. Rivets generally just get squeezed, they don’t get torque applied.

Comment: Not interested in unverifiable anecdotes, but actual evidence. Like a link to a product.

Comment: I'll back isherwood on this, it's a rivet (some kind of). I guess that the three grooves are not for torque but some sort of stamping impression that "activates" the rivet. I was trying to open up to fix a multisocket extension cord once and I had found the same type of "screw" (with 2 grooves instead of 3). I decided to drill through them only to find that there were no threads on the rest of the body of the "screw". Hence, it is some kind of "rivet" (a non-removable fixture).

Comment: I don't think anyone would use a rivet to secure plastic pieces...you'd wreck the plastic.

Comment: I don't think you've looked inside many plastic things. It's extremely common, and _you_ aren't doing the riveting--robots are in many cases, or factory workers with purpose-built equipment. (I've attempted to fix many plastic toys, being appalled by the plastic waste in the modern world.)

Comment: You definitely get rivets in plastic things. You also get metal pins that aren't really rivets but may as well be (they're barbed rather than getting peened on assembly, and engage with features in the plastic). You definitely get rivets with locating features in the head. While I haven't come across this particular combination of 3 locating grooves on a rivet, it wouldn't be a surprise and I've also never seen a security screwdriverbit like this (2 opposite grooves, yes, I've got the tool for that). So it's quite likely to be a rivet or equivalent